# Angular Material Design md-primary not showing desired color

Tags: angularjs, material-design

I am using Angular Material Design button, and assign class "md-icon-button md-primary" to it. The code snippet is shown below.

```
<md-button aria-label="Subscribe" class="md-icon-button md-primary">
  <md-icon md-svg-icon="img/ic_alarm_on_black_24px.svg"></md-icon>
</md-button>
```

The icon of the button is correct, but **the 'md-primary' color is not applied**. I tried other icons at https://material.io/icons/, and tried other class like "md-accent", but no luck at the moment.

Any hints to solve the issue would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, because i had no problem with it. Did you try to apply another class?

```
<md-button aria-label="Subscribe" class="md-icon-button md-accent">
  <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> accessibility </md-icon>
</md-button>

<md-button aria-label="Subscribe" class="md-icon-button md-primary">
  <md-icon md-font-set="material-icons"> accessibility </md-icon>
</md-button>
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/grishkovelli/yn7Lsep3/)